# brew.rb Permission denied

Tags: macos, homebrew

I was trying to `brew update` when I got suddenly a permission error:

`/usr/local/bin/brew: line 28: /usr/local/Library/brew.rb: Permission denied
/usr/local/bin/brew: line 28: exec: /usr/local/Library/brew.rb: cannot execute: Undefined error: 0`

I also tried `sudo brew update`, but without any luck.

What can I do?

Comment: Run brew doctor to look for errors. You never need to run sudo brew  the chown answer below will probably work. My guess is some installer was crappy and change usr/local to be owned by root (or OS X did it for you on upgrade )

Comment: This is actually a problem running brew at all—`brew doctor` will produce the same error message.

Answer (score 8):

The way that worked for me was to do as @happylookout suggested.

```
cd /usr/local
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/master
```

However, you may get a permissions error such as:

```
error: unable to unlink old 'bin/brew' (Permission denied)
error: unable to unlink old 'share/man/man1/brew.1' (Permission denied)
fatal: Could not reset index file to revision 'origin/master'.
```

To fix this, you need to run the last command above with sudo:

```
sudo git reset --hard origin/master
```

Now you should be able to run `brew update` without errors.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem just now and solved it by updating the whole thing via git:

```
cd /usr/local
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try running this

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local
```

Comment: @AndrewMedico: I'm calling bs on that — [the Homebrew project troubleshooting section suggests it](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/Troubleshooting.md#troubleshooting). If there's any reason someone should believe differently without explanation then No, don't take pointless comments as advice and do what the documentation suggests.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled brew and reinstalled it. Fixed the problem.